# Edit and Update modal in laravel 10

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem regarding the edit data will not save to the row that I choose to edit but the last/latest row of the data for the current user. The edit modal shows the correct data of the selected row but when I try to save it, it always updates to the last row, no matter any row I choose. This is my edit.blade.php

```
<form id="edit-form" action="{{ route('accounts.update', $account->account_id) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('PUT')
   <div class="mb-3">
     <label for="accountType">Account Type</label>
     <select name="account_type" value="{{ $account->account_type }}" id="modal-account-type">
        <option value="General" {{ $account->account_type === 'General' ? 'selected' : ''}}>General</option>
        ...
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
     <label for="accountName">Account Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="account_name" id="modal-account-name" value="{{ $account->account_name }}" required>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="account_id" id="modal-account-id">
   <div class="flex mt-6 justify-center">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is my edit modal javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // For showing edit item popup
    $(document).on('click', ".editAccountBtn", function() {
        // Get the data
        var el = $(this); // The clicked button
        var accountId = el.data('item-id');
        var row = el.closest(".data-row");

        // Find the elements within the row and get the data
        var accountType = row.find(".type").text();
        var accountName = row.find(".name").text();

        // Fill the data in the input fields
        $("#modal-account-id").val(accountId);
        $("#modal-account-type").val(accountType);
        $("#modal-account-name").val(accountName);

        var options = {
            'backdrop': 'static'
        };
        $('#editAccountModal').modal(options);
    });

    // On modal hide
    $('#editAccountModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
        $("#edit-form").trigger("reset");
    });
});
```

Comment: Easy enough to check if your javascript is setting the correct ID for the hidden field account_id by looking at the form submission with network tools in the browser or by dumping the request in the controller.